# How to set up relational database tables for this many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

I have a type of data called a `chain`. Each `chain` is made up of a specific sequence of another type of data called a `step`. So a `chain` is ultimately made up of multiple `steps` in a specific order. I'm trying to figure out the best way to set this up in MySQL that will allow me to do the following:

1. Look up all steps in a chain, and get them in the right order
2. Look up all chains that contain a step

I'm currently considering the following table set up as the appropriate solution:

```
TABLE chains
id   date_created

TABLE steps
id   description

TABLE chains_steps  (this would be used for joins)
chain_id   step_id   step_position
```

In the table `chains_steps`, the `step_position` column would be used to order the steps in a chain correctly. It seems unusual for a JOIN table to contain its own distinct piece of data, such as `step_position` in this case. But maybe it's not unusual at all and I'm just inexperienced/paranoid.

I don't have much experience in all this so I wanted to get some feedback. Are the three tables I suggested the correct way to do this? Are there any viable alternatives and if so, what are the advantages/drawback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right.

Consider a database containing the `Employees` and `Projects` tables, and how you'd want to link them in a many-to-many fashion. You'd probably come up with an `Assignments` table (or `Project_Employees` in some naming conventions).

At some point you'd decide you want not only to store each project assignment, but you'd also want to store when the assignment started, and when it finished. The natural place to put that is in the assignment itself; it doesn't make sense to store it either with the project or with the employee.

In further designs you might even find it necessary to store further information about the assignment, for example in an employee review process you may wish to store feedback related to their performance in that project, so you'd make the assignment the "one" end of a relationship with a `Review` table, which would relate back to `Assignments` with a FK on `assignment_id`.

So in short, it's perfectly normal to have a junction table that has its own data.

Comment: Thanks for the developed example on extra data in the junction table!

Answer (score 1):

That looks fine, and it's not unusual for the join table to contain a position/rank field.

Look up all steps in a chain, and get them in the right order

```
SELECT * FROM chains_steps 
  LEFT JOIN steps ON steps.id = chains_steps.step_id 
  WHERE chains_steps.chain_id = ? 
  ORDER BY chains_steps.step_position ASC
```

Look up all chains that contain a step

```
SELECT DISTINCT chain_id FROM chains_steps 
  LEFT JOIN chains ON chains.id = chains_steps.chain_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the plan you've outlined is the correct approach. Don't worry too much about the presence of `step_position` on your mapping table. After all the `step_position` is a bit of data that is directly related to a `step` in the context of a `chain`. So the `chains_steps` table is the right place for it IMHO.

Some things to think about:

1. Foreign keys - use 'em!
2. Unique key on the `chains_steps` table - can a step be present in more than one position in a single chain? What about in different chains?

Good luck!